# not able to change selected value in dropdown list for current academic year

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not able to change selected value for current academic year
I use the code below:

Asp.net

```
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <b><asp:Label ID="lblSelectAcYear" runat="server" Text="Select AcYear"></asp:Label></b>
    </td>
    <td>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAcYear" runat="server" OnDataBinding="ddlBinding" OnDataBound="ddlAcYear_DataBound" AutoPostBack="true" Width="150px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlAcYear_SelectedIndexChanged">

    </asp:DropDownList>
    </td>
    <td><b><asp:Label ID="lblSelectSem" runat="server" Text="Select Semester"></asp:Label></b></td>
    <td>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSelectSem" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Selected="True" Text="Even"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Odd"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

And Code behind

```
        ddlAcYear.DataSource = Res.AllData;
            ddlAcYear.DataValueField = "AcYearId";

            ddlAcYear.DataTextField = "AcYear";
            ddlAcYear.DataBind();
            foreach (DataRow dr in Res.AllData.Rows)
            {
                if ((DateTime.Now.Date > Convert.ToDateTime(dr.ItemArray[2]).Date && DateTime.Now.Date < Convert.ToDateTime(dr.ItemArray[3]).Date))
                {

                    ddlAcYear.SelectedValue = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();



                }

            }
```

When I debug, selected value is showing correct but when the page is displayed, the first item in the dropdown list is shown. :'(

Comment: I am calling the code behind in Page_Load() and dr.ItemArray[2] contains startdate (date) and dr.ItemArray[3] contains enddate (date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I have always selected items in a dropdown:

```
 ListItem liId = ddlAcYear.Items.FindByValue(dr.ItemArray[0].ToString());
 if (liId != null) {
     liId.Selected = true;
 }
```

Comment: I have tried it too, both techniqs show selectedvalue to '6' which is for 2013-14 but when the page is displayed, first AcYear i.e 2008-09 is displayed as selected.

Comment: Are you binding your dropdown in Page_Load?